# Passing external PHP variable into html script tag for leaflet map

Tags: javascript, php, variables, leaflet, geojson

I'm attempting to pass a variable from a php file that gets executed upon a button click that queries a database. Within the php file a variable that is an array gets populated and then needs to be passed back to the html so that I can use it to filter my geojson points for a leaflet map. If I hard code the variable "filterlist" inside the html script tag, the filter works fine and the points are displayed on the map.  If I comment that line out of the html script tag (as is shown in the sample html code below), the map doesn't display anything.  Obviously I'm incorrectly passing the variable from the external php script to use in the html script tag but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  It's been getting very frustrating as I've been working on this for a while now.  Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is a snippet of the code. If you need anything else just let me know and I'll respond promptly.

The PHP file (searchDataset.php):

```
<?
$UniqueIDsPass = ['Dane_5802790', 'Dane_5803376', 'Dane_5803377', 'Dane_5803025', 'Dane_5778080'];
$filterlist2 = json_encode($UniqueIDsPass);
>?
<script type="text/javascript">var  filterlist = "<?= $filterlist2 ?>";</script>
```

The html code (test2.html):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Testing Web Mapping</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet/leaflet.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet/MarkerCluster.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="tabcontent.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="moveitems2.js"></script>
        <script src="leaflet/leaflet-ui.js"></script>   
        <script src="leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src="leaflet/leaflet.ajax.min.js"></script>
        <script src="leaflet/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div id="map" style="width:700px; height: 850px"></div>
</div>
<form id="FilterForm" method="post" action="searchDataset.php" target='resultsFrame'>
    <button onclick="listboxSelectAll();">Search Button</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
                            
    var map = L.map('map',{
        center:[44.4340101, -90.0139754], 
        zoom:7});
    var usgs = L.tileLayer.wms("http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/ArcGIS/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/WMSServer", {layers:'0', format: 'image/png', transparent: true, attribution: "USGS"}).addTo(map);
                            
    var PointsStyle = {
        "radius": 4,
        "color": "#fb0f04", 
        "fillColor": "#fb0f04",
        "weight": 1,
        "opacity": 1,
        "fillOpacity": 0
    };
                            
    function FilterSales(layer) {
        return filterlist.includes(layer.properties.UniqueID)
    }
                            
    //var filterlist = ['Dane_5802790', 'Dane_5803376', 'Dane_5803377', 'Dane_5803025', 'Dane_5778080'];

    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
    var Sale_points = L.geoJSON.ajax('GIS/Sales_points_geojson.geojson', {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return markers.addLayer(L.circleMarker(latlng, PointsStyle));
        }, filter: FilterSales
    }).addTo(map);
                            
    map.addLayer(markers)
                            
    var Sale_polys = L.geoJSON.ajax('GIS/Sales_polygons_geojson.geojson', 
        {style: PolygonsStyle, onEachFeature: SalesTooltips, filter: FilterSales});
                                
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two syntax errors in the php file:

1. On line 4 it should be ?> and not the other way around
2. On line 5 remove the quotes around `<?= $filterlist2 ?>`

That should fix the syntax errors in your php code. If you want to use the filterlist2 javascript variable in your html you should generate the html in the php file. Javascript variables don't persist when you are causing a new page reload. So combining the two files you should have just the following test2.php file.

test2.php:

```php
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Testing Web Mapping</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet/leaflet.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet/MarkerCluster.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="tabcontent.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
        
<?
$UniqueIDsPass = ['Dane_5802790', 'Dane_5803376', 'Dane_5803377', 'Dane_5803025', 'Dane_5778080'];
$filterlist2 = json_encode($UniqueIDsPass);
?>
        <script type="text/javascript">var  filterlist = <?= $filterlist2 ?>;</script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="moveitems2.js"></script>
        <script src="leaflet/leaflet-ui.js"></script>   
        <script src="leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src="leaflet/leaflet.ajax.min.js"></script>
        <script src="leaflet/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div id="map" style="width:700px; height: 850px"></div>
</div>
<form id="FilterForm" method="post" action="searchDataset.php" target='resultsFrame'>
    <button onclick="listboxSelectAll();">Search Button</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
                            
    var map = L.map('map',{
        center:[44.4340101, -90.0139754], 
        zoom:7});
    var usgs = L.tileLayer.wms("http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/ArcGIS/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/WMSServer", {layers:'0', format: 'image/png', transparent: true, attribution: "USGS"}).addTo(map);
                            
    var PointsStyle = {
        "radius": 4,
        "color": "#fb0f04", 
        "fillColor": "#fb0f04",
        "weight": 1,
        "opacity": 1,
        "fillOpacity": 0
    };
                            
    function FilterSales(layer) {
        return filterlist.includes(layer.properties.UniqueID)
    }

    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
    var Sale_points = L.geoJSON.ajax('GIS/Sales_points_geojson.geojson', {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return markers.addLayer(L.circleMarker(latlng, PointsStyle));
        }, filter: FilterSales
    }).addTo(map);
                            
    map.addLayer(markers)
                            
    var Sale_polys = L.geoJSON.ajax('GIS/Sales_polygons_geojson.geojson', 
        {style: PolygonsStyle, onEachFeature: SalesTooltips, filter: FilterSales});
                                
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at the code parapente.  Your point #1 was just an error when I typed that section out on here, it was correct in the original but good catch.  For line #5, it now looks like <script type="text/javascript">var filterlist = <?= $filterlist2 ?>;</script> but it doesn't affect the map at all.  When I use the firefox developer tools I get an Uncaught ReferenceError: filterlist is not defined.

Comment: Sorry the tags were being removed from the stack overflow parser.

Comment: I'm hoping the Uncaught ReferenceError might be a dead giveaway for someone more knowledgeable than I am about this.

Comment: @BrandonMoore You shouldn't get Uncaught Reference if the variable is created in the same file that is creating the html you use above. See my updated answer.

Comment: Ok this is starting to make sense to me now parapente.  I guess I was always taught modularity when it comes to programming (python, matlab) but I guess to accomplish what I'm trying to do requires a much longer single script instead.  I'll work on what you provided and fill in the rest of the coding.  Thank you so much for the example, it always helps me learn better.

Comment: One last question for you parapente, in the original question the button click ran the searchDatabase.php file.  In the example you provided (which I now understand) you moved the contents of the original php file within the php tags but the action is still set to searchDataset.php on the form.  How do I reference the code within those php tags when the user clicks the Search Button?  Hope that makes sense you.

Comment: I can only guess from your pasted code as it is not complete but you probably just need to change `action="searchDataset.php"` in the form tag to `action="test2.php"`.